# Remove an object in a List after several seconds XNA C#

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm planning to make a shooting game where player can see how many points they got shooting enemies by "+ the score". Each of them I have added in into a `List` like this:

```
scoreList.Add(new ScoreHUD(Content.Load<SpriteFont>(@"arial"), 20, new Vector2(e.position.X, e.position.Y)));
```

20 is the score gotten to kill something. This shows "+20" in the position of every enemy killed without problem.

Now, I'm trying to remove them from game after like 3 seconds being shown. I have tried wiring a timer function in `Update` function but have no idea (and I think it is bad practice) how to wire each timer function into each score. Is there any way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple example where the removal of an item is called every 2 seconds.

```
//Declares a timespan of 2 seconds
TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);


public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Decrements the timespan
    timeSpan -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;

    // If the timespan is equal or smaller time "0"
    if (timeSpan <= TimeSpan.Zero )
    {
        // Remove the object from list
        scoreList.RemoveAt(1);
        // Re initializes the timespan for the next time
        timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);

    }

    base.Update(gameTime)
}
```

I hope this help you

Comment: I just need to change the code so it checks if the list contains anything and change removeat(1) to removeat(0) and it works like charm! thanks!

Comment: Thank you, it is always a pleasure to help someone ^^.

Answer (score 0):

ok... i will explain with pseudo code, i will go like this:

```
class ScoreList
  Position (vector)
  Value (string)
  Duration (integer) = 60 ' 1 second
  visible = false
end class

class Score
  inhertis list of scorelist

  sub add(position, value, duration)
    ' add position, set visible to true
  end sub
  sub update()
    for each score in me
      if score visible
         score.duration -= 1
         if score.duration < 1 then score.visible = false;
      end if
    end for

    score.removeAll(function(c) c.visible = false) ' to remove unused
  end sub

  sub draw()
    for each score in me
      if score.visible then draw it
    end if
  end sub

end class
```

Comment: i did use this logic, put lifetime on each score class, in update of the score class i decrement it and make it invisible, but it didn't work, thanks anyway

Comment: by that code i control everything (enemies, starfield, bullets, powerups...) and it works.